# union: strange behavior [c]

Tags: c, unions

It is said: *"A union is a special class type that **can hold only one** of its non-static data members at a time."* (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union)

**But how can it hold more that one member?**

`y` is of 8 bytes and `x` is of 4 bytes. The size of union is the size of the MAX element (8 bytes). It cannot hold 4 + 8 = 12 bytes...

I'm confused.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

union number {
    int x;
    double y;
};

int main()
{
    union number value;

    // ok
    value.x = 1;
    printf("\n   int: %5d\ndouble:    %f\n", value.x, value.y);

    // ok
    value.y = 1.0;
    printf("\n   int: %5d\ndouble:   %f\n", value.x, value.y);

    // NOT OK! But if I swap `value.x and value.y` it will work properly...
    value.y = 1.0;
    value.x = 1;
    printf("\n   int: %5d\ndouble:     %f\n", value.x, value.y);


    return 0;
}
```

The output is [image: OUTPUT]

Comment: I'm not looking for something. I learn C-language and this is one of themes (..., union, enum, ...).  I can't realize how can it store two elements at a time?

Comment: The behavior is not "strange", but "undefined".  You must not read a union member if that member was not the last member assigned.

Comment: Here's a theory: first, you set the low part of that double to 1, the upper part is in some random uninitialized state that apparently just happened to be 0x80000000, together they don't actually come out as -0.0 but close enough that it might print that. The rest of the behaviour is also consistent with aliasing the int with the lowest dword of the double combined with the print routine not caring so much about the lowest bit of the double.

Comment: @harold Yeah, that's exactly what's happening: taken to more digits past the decimal, I get `double:     1.000000000000000222044605` for the last value.

Comment: Please don't post graphics for simple textual contents such as this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The union allocates enough memory for the "largest" datatype.

As an example, If union would contain uint8_t a, uint16_t b. The data would align as follow

```
Bits LSB   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15   MSB
Uint8_t  a -------------->
Uint16_t b ------------------------------------>
Var b=     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1 in binary
```

And If you look at var a. It will give you in binary 00000001, 128 in decimal.
`
O well, I dont know if I confused you even more now :).

Comment: Good graphic. I think this is more what OP was asking.

Comment: If both variables contains the same value in beginning, it doesn't matter. What i am trying to say, if he sets var a to 128 and var b to 65408 he want notice that var b have written over var a.

Answer (score 1):

A union can have as many members as you want, but only one member at a time is valid. This is because all members of a union *shares* the same memory. So if you change one member, then the others will change as well. However, assigning to one member, and then access another may not produce the results you expect, since often the layout in memory is different. This is the case of `int` and `double`, one can't be used as another.

What you're looking for is a [*structure*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29):

```
struct number
{
    int x;
    double y;
};
```

The above contain two *separate* members, that can both be used at the same time as they no longer share the same memory.

Comment: So how can you explain the 3-rd part of output?

Comment: Since the variables use the same memory (that's how a union works), changing one will change the other (it'll actually change *all* members of the union). The exact value depends on the memory layout.

Comment: @YulianKhlevnoy Very easily: *Undefined behavior*. Since the last assignment was to the integer, the value of the double is undefined. Printing the double could output anything.

Comment: This is the first really *Undefined behavior* in my life so I'm really confused. So, this problem is not worth solving? But I cannot give up with this...

Comment: @YulianKhlevnoy If the problem you try to solve is to have a structure containing two separate and distinct member variables, then you need to use `struct`. Otherwise I'm not sure what the problem you're trying to solve is.